# SELECTing data using a Postgres Array

Tags: arrays, postgresql

I have a table that contains a column `user_ids` which is a Postgres Array.

I need to select all `messages` from another table where the column `user_id` is one of the ids in the given array.

In Psuedo-sql:

```
select users.*
from users
where id IN a_postgres_array
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select users.*
from users
where id IN (
    select unnest(a_postgres_array)
    from t
    where columnX = some_value
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `ANY` operator. From your sample:

```
select users.*
from users
where id =ANY(a_postgres_array)
```

When using two tables, it could be a `JOIN`, something like:

```
SELECT users.*
FROM users INNER JOIN table_with_array ON users.id =ANY(table_with_array.a_postgres_array)
```